# directory index of "/var/www/myapp/current/public/" is forbidden

Tags: nginx

After upgrading nginx from `1.12.2` to `1.18.0` I started getting this error:

```
[error] 21476#21476: *52 directory index of "/var/www/myapp/current/public/" is forbidden, client: 78.185.30.219, server: myapp.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", host: "myapp.com"
```

although it was working before the upgrade, and no permissions has changed, also, I kept using the previous nginx config.

note, that application is served with passenger

any idea?

Comment: This error usually means that Nginx cannot find an `index.html` file in that directory.

Comment: It was working normally before the upgrade of nginx, I did not change anything in that directory

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, I have upgraded passenger to version `6.0.7` while it was `5.1.12`